# Listview in Listview problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

How ca i use a listview in a listview?
I have a list of items an each item has a list of tags.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title")%>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server"            
             DataSource='<%#getTagDatasource((string)Eval("tags"))%>'>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>'></asp:Label></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The datasource for the second listview is a string array that contains the array of tags contained in the tags column(is a single string separated wit an ','. the data source string array i form in the getTagDatasource method with a tags.split(','))  in the table.

Now this doesn't work because it says Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getTagDatasource method, do this at teh beginning:

```
public string[] getTagDatasource(object data)
{
    if (!(data is string) || data == null)
       return new string[] { };

    return data.ToString().Split(",");
}
```

Check for invalid data first.

HTH.